# SQL Server - How to access sequence with schema in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sequence, database-schema

I have stored procedure and sequence with schema (MY_SCHEMA) in SQL Server like this:

```
Sequence > MY_SCHEMA.SEQ_GLOBAL
Stored Procedure > MY_SCHEMA.SP_GLOBAL
```

When i execute `select * from sys.sequences`, i can see the sequence name is not included the schema, which is only `SEQ_GLOBAL`

And this is part of my stored procedure that trying to access a sequence created with schema

```
DECLARE @seq_name  VARCHAR(255) = 'SEQ_GLOBAL';
DECLARE @sql       NVARCHAR(1000);


SET @sql = 'SELECT @nextSeq = NEXT VALUE FOR ' + @seq_name;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@nextSeq int output', @p_stan OUTPUT;
```

When i try to run this stored procedure, i got this error:

> Invalid object name 'SEQ_GLOBAL'.

I also try to change the @seq_name to include schema

```
DECLARE @seq_name  VARCHAR(255) = 'MY_SCHEMA.SEQ_GLOBAL';
```

But then i got a different error:

> Sequence not found

But when i recreate the sequence without MY_SCHEMA and it works.

```
sequence > dbo.SEQ_GLOBAL

in store procedure
   DECLARE @seq_name  VARCHAR(255) = 'SEQ_GLOBAL';
```

Can anyone point me how to access sequence with schema inside stored procedure ?
Thanks.

Comment: `sys.sequences` has all the columns of `sys.objects`, meaning there is a `schema_id` pointing to a row in `sys.schemas`. However, if your stored procedure is part of the same schema, it would be able to access the sequence without further qualification. This suggests the schema is not what you think it is.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Aside... object names are of the `sysname` data type, which is currently a [user-defined datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql#remarks) equivalent to `nvarchar(128) not null`.